# Cannot find "Start Recording" button in VS Web Essentials 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, web-essentials, browser-link

I am pulling my hair off here... Why on earth is `Start Recording` button which is shown in every tutorial is not where it is supposed to be in Web Essentials 2015?

Here is the picture of the available options in the Browser Link Menu...

[image]

And here is the Browser Link Dashboard screenshow...

[image]

I'm looking for it in order to see the unused css in my project. There is no new documents I could find on google. And Web Essentials web page is not showing anything new.

I'm using VS2015 Community Edition with Web Essentials 2015 today's latest build.

Comment: facing the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet... Popularity of this question is way too low at the moment :(
If you find something, will appreciate if you post as answer, though ;)

Comment: @ilter Try to post same on Github repos for Webessential 2015.

Comment: Did you find the solution?

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find that one in the time, and gave up looking for it. If you find, post here an answer though. I will mark it as the answer.

Comment: Not working for me too. Unused CSS rules is a very helpful feature, let's hope it will work on VS2017

Answer (score 0):

I had a same issue and found that Web Essential 2015 does not have Unused CSS feature. Thats why start recording is missing. Had to install VS2013 with Update 5 with Resharper to build C#6.0 code and with Web Essential 2013 to make it work.